# Fixing image in center of toolbar Android

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working whit Xamarin pcl. Now has the Android project an auto rendered layout for Toolbar and Tabbar. I am customizing the toolbar.axml to have a icon in the center of it. Everything is going wel untill a page got a back button (navigation page attribute I guess) end the icon shifts to the right because its not anymore the only one in the toolbar. Is there an easy fix to give the icon a fixed position? The back-button, I think, is not declared in an axml but generated through the function of Xamarin.Forms new NavigationPage().

My axml looks now like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#72B1A2"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >
  <ImageView
   android:id="@id/image"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   android:paddingBottom="5dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:src="@drawable/ictzaak_FC"
    />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I already look into the use of android:layout_gravity="center" and android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" and android:center_horizontal or something but it didn't fix it

How it looks:
[Startup screen without the return button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFqeV.png)

[With return button and out of center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNtUq.png)

Comment: also make sure that the inherited style in your toolbar is override in you xml by adding this to you toolbar,   app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"

Comment: Where do I add that? In the manifest or in the toolbar.axml?

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:gravity="center"
   app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to nest the Image in a RelativeLayout. And in this you can center your Image. Like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#72B1A2"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/image"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ictzaak_FC"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: It should work but I think it's not working because that the back-button widget gets added to the left side of the relativelayout so its all shifted to the right. Can I define the backbutton also in the same axml without crashing xamarin forms pcl?

Comment: @ICTzaakDEV well, I'm not an expert in Xamarin. But if you know the width of the backbutton you could set android:layout_marginLeft="-buttonWidth" for the image.

Comment: Okay thanks anyways, I am going to try make something like that!

Comment: It isn't fixed still but i removed the back button in the page because it doesn't have anything to do with the overall purpose of the app. But still, it would be a nice feature to have and I am still trying to get a fix. If I got something I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Image set in center using LinearLayout.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/image"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_img"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: The back button gets added dynamicly before linearlayout, that is how the navigationpage works in Xamarin Forms. If it got added in the linearlayout than it could be fixed this way